# android: set text field position, dynamic position, in java

Tags: android, position, coordinates, textfield

I'm new at android programming.

How can I set the position of a textfield from a .java file activity? (I dont want to change it from the .xml file)
I already tried :

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom); //use ints here
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Thanks
sorry for my poor english

Comment: set position to where? what is your problem at the moment?